# PHP rand() returns same number everytime

Tags: php, random

I basically have a HTML form where the user inputs the number of random numbers to be generated and their range. The problem is, every time I try to generate a random set of numbers, I get `$count` times `$max` displayed.

This is the PHP code:

```
    <?php
    $count=$_GET['count'];
    $min=$_GET['max'];
    $max=$_GET['max'];
    $i=0;
    while ($i<$count) {
        echo rand($min,$max) . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: $min=$_GET['max']; $max=$_GET['max']; same ?

Comment: its possible for a random number generator to return the same number if called an infinite number of times. that's the nature of random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $count=$_GET['count'];
    $min=$_GET['min'];
    $max=$_GET['max'];
    $i=0;
    while ($i<$count) {
        echo rand($min,$max) . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

You are setting `$min` and `$max` both to you `$_GET['max']` value

Comment: Silly me, I should have noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your $min and $max are both set to $_GET['max'] ...